# can you leave the airport if you have a long wait on a connecting flight

Tags: transit, china

am thinking of flying to Beijing before  going on to Phuket. One of the connecting times at Beijing airport is 9 hours. Do you have to stay in the airport for all of the time. or do get an opportunity to go out and explore?

TIA

Comment: Please provide information on your citizenship.

Comment: What passport are you using?

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly leave the airport as long as you have proper entry credentials for the country. You either need a full visa for China or depending on your citizenship you may be able to get a transit Visa: https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/free-72hour/